Conditional Ctrl-Alt-Del shutdown
I always shutdown my Linuxes with Ctrl-Alt-Del from a virtual console (outside any window mangager - KDE).
Now I want that the system still shutdowns with Ctrl-Alt-Del, but only if certain CONDITION is satisfied. (That condition is the existence of a file.)
Something like this:
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! CONDITION ]]; then

    echo
    echo "  *************************"
    echo "  *************************"
    echo "  **                     **"
    echo "  **   WRONG CONDITION   **"
    echo "  **                     **"
    echo "  *************************"
    echo "  *************************"
    echo
else
    sudo shutdown -h now
fi

I guess that I can do a service/target thing, but I have failed miserably....
EDIT: I do not need this to be through anything special, in particular, not with a service/target. This was just the thing I tried. I just want to Ctrl-Alt-Del from a virtual console after logout, and the system to execute the script above instead of the system poweroff. Maybe by recreating a symlink pointing to my script instead of poweroff, or whatever.

this can be very easy, or involve a lot of "working around": it's easy if you can write a program that will exit the moment that CONDITION is fulfilled, and you have a way of noticing when CONDITION stops being fulfilled. What is that CONDITION? As in, logically/technically, not in terms of bash scripting

I want to shutdown with Ctrl-Alt-Del as always, but only if CONDITION is satisfied. The actual CONDITION is not relevant.

it really is relevant, as I try to explain… your approach doesn't work, but there's easy ways to do something that works, but they depend on the nature of your condition. You will need to help us help you by actually answering questions!

Existence of a file.

Hm, could the thing that creates the file also start execute or stop a process? One could work around if that's not possible, but it would add layers of file system watching complexity.

I just want to press Ctrl-Alt-Del and, if file exists, the system shutdowns, if it doesn't exist, it prints a warning and exits, without shutting down. I have no control on what or when the file exists or was created, and this script is executed EXCLUSIVELY after a Ctrl-Alt-Del. That is, instead of the poweroff process, I want the system to call my script.

that is simply not how things work, and you repeating what you want to do doesn't help that fact :) But there's specific inhibitors for this purpose, which you can make use of.

@MarcusMüller why? If the user writes a little script that just does something like [ -e /whatever/file ] && shutdown -h now, if that is then mapped to Ctrl+Alt+Del as a keyboard shortcut using their GUI or even xbindkeys, then they should be all set, right?

@terdon on OP's machine, ctrl-alt-del seems to be handled already by systemd, what they ask for is a proper way to "hook" systemd shutdown, at least how I read the question,right?

I don't really know if Ctrl+Alt+Del is "special" or if it can simply be bound by higher level GUI stuff, but I think it can. I think I have used GUI tools to control it in the past.

@terdon you probably haven't seen it, but the user insists that this must work from the console after ending the graphical session manually (see the comments under my answer), and that the solution should directly write to the console, no matter what else is going on there…

@MarcusMüller I have seen the comments yes, and all I saw was the OP saying what they do now, not that it is a requirement. After all, disabling plymouth to see the booting messages has no bearing on whether you then need to shut down from the console. In any case, what is in the question is just "how can I map ctrl+alt+del to shutdown only if a file exists" which really doesn't seem that complicated. It seems very strange to bring in systemd or any other such complication.

@terdon [tag:systemd] is a tag, though, and OP does mention "service/target", so I'm pretty confident this is a requirement. Wouldn't they have mentioned if they'd set up something that watches e.g. evdev/libinput to capture ctrl-alt-del if it wasn't what their system already brought?

@LuisA.Florit please [edit] your question and clarify exactly what you need. Do you really need this to work from a non-GUI environment? Do you need it to be done via systemd? Would you be open to just using a different shortcut that maps to running a simple script? As you can see, we are having trouble understanding what you need.

the user insists that this must work from the console after ending the graphical session manually (see the comments under my answer), and that the solution should directly write to the console, no matter what else is going on there. Yes, exactly. When I logout from KDE, sync scripts are triggered. After they are all finished, the session ends, getting a virtual 1990 console prompt. I want to Ctrl-Alt-Del from there.

@terdon Yes, I thought this should be pretty easy, like recreating a symlink that points to poweroff to mypoweroff, or something like that.

@terdon: I edited my question, I hope it is more clear now: Ctrl-Alt-Del from a virtual console after logout should execute my own script instead of the system poweroff. That is why I wrote that CONDITION is irrelevant. This cannot be so hard!

Well, it's a really odd requirement since shortcut keys aren't really something one uses in the command line. Why not just have a function called s or any other single letter that runs your script? What benefit in using a complicated, three key "shortcut" instead of just s and enter? Entirely your choice, of course, and if that's what you prefer, then that's what you prefer, but it isn't surprising that there's no widely known easy way to do this.

There is a good reason why you need a 3 letter combination for poweroff: not to trigger it by accident. So why a single letter? In fact, I do use virtual consoles quite frequently. Sometimes I don't want to login into KDE to not trigger my sync scripts, sometimes something went wrong with KDE (e.g., the finger scanner stops working and I need to login through the virtual consoles, or Wayland incompatibility with X11 configs), root maintenance, and several other stuff. I wouldn't mind to press another combination instead of C-A-D, that would be fine. I am really surprised there is no easy way.

BTW, remember that I want to trigger the poweroff AFTER complete logout. So no command line, no s+ENTER. I'm logged out.

Two general ways to approach this (sadly, yours is neither!):

(easy) you write a program, shell script, anything, that exits as soon as CONDITION becomes fulfilled. You call that program using systemd-inhibit --what=shutdown myblockingprogram. Because you don't want to figure out whether it's been started before, and you wouldn't want to have a loop polling the CONDITION, ideally, this execution would automatically be triggered by some action that causes a notification.
In your case, where CONDITION is "existence of a file", that's a bit complicated in a shell script. But sure, either you have a loop doing the above invocation after checking existence of the file, with short sleep in between, so that you don't burn a CPU core just on checking. More elegantly:
(more general) you write your own shutdown inhibitor. That's explained in detail here, in the official documentation. You write a program (shell programming is not sufficient here; but python, C++, Go, Rust or C would totally do, for example) that calls the Inhibit() functionality, which returns a file descriptor. The moment you close that file descriptor, shutdowns begin to be allowed again. 
So, in this scenario, you would use inotify or fanotify to get notified when the target file gets created. When it gets created, you call the Inhibit functionality, get a file descriptor. You use inotify/fanotify to get notified about the file getting deleted. Once that file disappears, you close the file descriptor. You start this program automatically as systemd user or system service.


Does systemd-inhibit show an explanation what was inhibited, like in my script? My file is in a pen drive. I can also check if the pen drive is plugged in (not just mounted)?

where would you show that, even? That makes no sense; your script could only show that message on the console it's being run from, and people don't leave a console open to watch for such messages. But yes, some desktop environments will inform you that, and some even which, a program has inhibited shutdown.

I like to see the booting messages, so I have disabled the graphic boot. So, I always do  Ctrl-Alt-Del in the virtual console, after logging out from KDE.

well, OK, that still wouldn't make much sense; your script would have to have access to the current console. Anyways, yeah, again, your script approach doesn't work, you'll have to do something different – which is why I wrote this answer. If you want, you can always write to whatever thing you want to write to make a message shown in your inhibitor as described above. That's up to you.

echo "..." > /dev/console works perfectly for me.

yes, if you have access to the same console. Which a random program really shouldn't, to be completely honest. But yes, you can do that, if you want to.
